# Routing Apache ErrorDocument to a Laravel route

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, laravel-5

I'm using Laravel 5.1. I have this in my `.htaccess` file (these are only changes in the file, compared to the default):

```
Options -Indexes
ErrorDocument 403 /error-403
```

I also have a `js/` directory in my `public/` directory.

When I try to access the `/js/` directory in the browser, I don't get the `/error-403` route opened, as I'd expect. Instead I get Laravel's 404 HTTP error handler triggered (I get a 404 page from Laravel) and I don't understand why.

When I open `/error-403` directly in the browser, the corresponding view opens fine. Here are some interesting server variables which I see in PHP for both of these requests.

---

`/error-403`:

```
"REDIRECT_STATUS" => "200"
"REDIRECT_URL" => "/error-403"
"REQUEST_METHOD" => "GET"
"REQUEST_URI" => "/error-403"
```

---

`/js/`:

```
"REDIRECT_REDIRECT_REQUEST_METHOD" => "GET"
"REDIRECT_REDIRECT_STATUS" => "403"
"REDIRECT_STATUS" => "403"
"REDIRECT_URL" => "/error-403"
"REQUEST_METHOD" => "GET"
"REQUEST_URI" => "/js/"
```

---

To me it seems like Apache's redirecting the request to Laravel, but Laravel, instead of picking up the URL `/error-403`, picks up the URL `/js/` for which no route exists and then throws a 404.

Has anyone else encountered similar problems? What am I missing here? How can I set up Laravel so that Apache (and its `ErrorDocument` statement) redirects to a route defined in Laravel? And by "how", I mean how can I do it in a proper way, so it's not a hack. I guess I could create a custom middleware which would examine these server variables and correct the route, but this seems dirty and I don't know if I'm missing something here.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to overcome this problem, if anyone is interested.

I noticed the problem was in `Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request::prepareRequestUri()`. In this method only `REQUEST_URI` is taken into account, `REDIRECT_URL` isn't ever looked at.

Laravel uses `Illuminate\Http\Request` which is a child class of the previously mentioned one. If you look at the service container, you will see an instance of this class. So what I needed to do was to extend this class and override this method. So I did this:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http;

use Illuminate\Http\Request as LaravelRequest;

class Request extends LaravelRequest
{
    protected function prepareRequestUri()
    {
        if ((int) $this->server->get('REDIRECT_STATUS', '200') >= 400 && $this->server->has('REDIRECT_URL')) {
            $requestUri = $this->server->get('REDIRECT_URL');
            $this->server->set('REQUEST_URI', $requestUri);
            return $requestUri;
        }

        return parent::prepareRequestUri();
    }
}
```

So, if the `REDIRECT_STATUS` is over 400 and `REDIRECT_URI` exists, it will be used, otherwise it will fallback to framework default logic.

Finally, I had to instruct the framework to use my implementation and not its own. I did this by editing `public/index.php` and replacing `Illuminate\Http\Request::capture()` with `App\Http\Request::capture()`.

And now everything works as it should, at least from what I can tell. Apache error documents are being properly rendered by Laravel.